# How to find the first white pixel in a row of an image (OpenCV, C++)

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to detect the first pixel's coordinate position found with color white, for each line of an image. The objective is to find the white area's "maximum" position with the respect to the yy axis. I'm trying by doing this:

```
    Mat line;

    list<int> depths_p1;

    for (int j = 0; j < bin_inv1.size().height; j++)
    {
        line=bin_inv1.row(j);

        for (int i = bin_inv1.size().width -1; i>0; i--){

            if(line.at<uchar>(i,0) == 255){
                depths_p1.push_front(i);
                cout<<i<<endl;
                break;
            } 
        }
    }
```

Basically, it goes row by row, and in each row, from the right to the left (second for cycle) it finds the x coordinate of the first found white pixel.

For example, this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cYw5.png) has a width of `297` pixels. The results I got are wrong (shown bellow). Even if I replace the if condition with `bin_inv1.at<uchar>(i,j) == 255` the results are a little different (why?) and not good for what i see in the picture. How can I get what I want?

```
296
296
296
296
296
296
296
296
296
296
296
296
296
296
296
296
296
296
296
296
296
296
296
296
296
296
296
296
296
296
296
296
296
296
296
296
296
295
294
293
292
291
290
289
288
287
286
285
284
283
282
281
280
279
278
277
276
275
274
273
272
271
270
269
268
267
266
265
264
263
262
261
260
259
258
257
256
255
254
253
252
251
250
249
248
247
246
245
244
243
242
241
240
239
238
237
236
235
234
233
232
231
230
229
228
227
226
225
224
223
222
221
220
219
218
217
216
215
214
213
212
211
210
209
208
207
206
205
204
203
202
201
200
199
198
197
196
195
194
193
192
191
190
189
188
187
186
185
184
183
182
181
180
179
178
177
176
175
174
173
172
171
170
169
168
167
166
165
164
163
162
161
160
159
158
157
156
155
154
153
152
151
150
149
148
147
146
145
144
143
142
141
140
139
138
137
136
135
134
133
132
131
130
129
128
127
126
125
124
123
122
121
120
119
118
117
116
115
114
113
112
111
110
109
108
107
106
105
104
103
102
101
100
99
98
296
296
296
296
296
296
296
296
296
296
296
296
296
296
296
296
296
296
295
294
293
292
291
290
289
288
287
286
285
284
283
282
281
280
279
278
277
276
275
274
273
272
271
270
269
268
267
266
265
264
263
262
261
260
259
258
257
256
255
254
253
252
251
250
249
248
247
246
245
244
243
242
241
240
239
238
237
236
235
234
233
232
231
230
229
228
227
226
225
224
223
222
221
220
219
218
217
216
```

Comment: You have provided a screen-grab of your image with the window title, instead of your actual image. Please share your actual image as that may be the problem, for example if it is a JPEG.

Comment: is bin_inv1 really single channel? Did you try .at(j,i) access? It is (row,col)

Comment: or .at (0,i) in your current code

Comment: @MarkSetchell it's a section of the original image (variable "Mat bin_inv1"), that's why i show a print of the image.

Comment: @Micka i switched (0,i) and the results seem consistent :) thanks